# find LR(1) items of the first state

Tags: automata, formal-grammars, compilers, syntax, lr-k

I need to calculate the LR(1) items of the following grammar:

```
S -> E
E -> E + T
E -> T
T -> ID
T -> ( E )
```

I can not even calculate the first group {[S -> .E, $]} correctly,
I read and tried to run the algorithm and did not understand why the correct answer for state 0 should be the group of items:

```
{[S -> .E, $]; 
[E -> .E + T, $ / +];
[E -> .T, $ / +]; 
[T -> .ID, $ / +]; 
[T ->. (E), $ / +]}
```

I calculated I found that there are only 5 items in group 0:

```
{[S -> .E,$];
 [E -> .E + T,$];
 [E -> .T,$];
 [T -> .ID,$];
 [T ->. (E),$]}
```

someone can explain to me why there should be items with a "+", and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S\to.E$,\$.........$(1)$, now compute the closure of $E$, which is $E\to.E+T,$\$..........$(2)$ and $E\to.T,$\$.........$(3)$ use lookahead \$ because in $(1)$ after $E$ is \$ and $FIRST$ of \$ is \$ that's why lookahead is \$ in (2) and (3).

From $(2)$ you need to find the closure of $E$, which is   $E\to.E+T,+$........$(4)$ and
$E\to .T,+$.............$(5)$ use lookahead $+$ because in $(2)$  after $E$ is
$+T,$\$ and $FIRST$ of   $+T,$\$ is $+$ that's why lookahead is $+$ in $(4)$ and $(5).$

Now  combining $(2)$ and  $(4)$ we get
$E\to.E+T,$\$$/+$.

Similarly combining $(3)$ and  $(5)$ we get
$E\to .T,$\$$/+$.

Rest of the things left for you.

Comment: Thank u , very helpful